# DConf equivalent for KDE

Tags: kde, dconf, gsettings

GNOME and many window managers such as the Awesome WM use the GSettings settings database, with Dconf as the backend. What is the equivalent of this for KDE?

Also, we can edit GSettiings with the Dconf Editor application or the `gsettings` command line tool. For example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

Has somebody work with KDE's engine? What's its name? What tools are there to modify it (such as `dconf-editor` and `gsettings`)?

Finally, we can hack the GSettings engine with `gsettings get`; how can I do this in KDE?

Comment: afaik there is no equivalent software. In KDE you have to use `systemsetting` or manually edit the config files in `~/.kde/share/config`. As an example, to edit the order of the titlebar buttons you would have to edit `~/.kde/share/config/kwinrc`, section `[style]` or find the relevant section in System Settings.

Comment: Oh no, i don't set titlebar, i want to know name of KDE engine.

Comment: KDE has `dcop` to send messages to a KDE application, and you can sometimes set preferences with the right message, but that isn't a very close match.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh you didn't read his answer. he said that as an example. also, FWIW, I believe FreeDesktop has/is standardizing on Dconf (but not GSettings) as a settings backed/engine.

Comment: The display manager itself is kdm, but that doesn't help you talk to it. Although this doesn't address your question directly, you may want to check out kstart. It's very hard to find good documentation on it, Basically, it allows you to start an application like you would do normally, but also tell KDE what to do with it such as where and how large it's window should be and on what virtual desktop. It might satisfy a few of your needs.

Comment: @Gilles KDE hasn't used dcop since the KDE 3.x days. Since KDE 4.0 it uses dbus,  same as gnome.

Comment: We can use sed to get the system default values changed, but one other nice feature of dconf / gsettings is that you can have 'override' files.  Meaning you don't touch the actual system level default files (that will be overwritten when they upgrade) but rather you can put files in /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas with an extension of "gschema.override".  If there are multiple override files that set settings differently, "last one wins".

Comment: <continued from above comment> Anyway, this allows us to have many different user locations with different default settings for their location, while at the same time it doesn't fight with the upstream gnome default settings.  So I am wondering if there is any way to work with adjusting the system default settings on kde without interfering with the exact files that will be overwritten as kde updates?  I will possibly start a new question but thought it most relevant to start here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the corresponding settings saved in `.kde/share/config/kioslaverc`.

Comment: What is the path for ".kde"?

Answer (score 5):

KDE doesn't use dconf. In KDE, settings are stored in simple text files rather than a database. The GUI for changing these settings is systemsettings, although individual application settings are usually set within the application.

Comment: According to Dawit Alemayehu, there'd be an api for it. And there'd be no guarantees that the conf file format'd be compatible. Apps reading the conf files directly without using the api'd be broken. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=288002#c3

Comment: @把友情留在无盐 There are APIs for accessing particular data, as there are with most operating systems and DEs, but there is no central database of configuration information like with dconf.